# How to treat typeof two T's as equal if they have same constraints?

Tags: c#, reflection

Suppose I have two generic methods:

```
static void Foo<T>(T argument) { }
static void Bar<T>(T argument) { }
```

The following code returns *false* because the  two `T` belong different types and they may have different constraints:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var foo = typeof (Program).GetMethod("Foo", flags)bar.GetParameters()[0];
var bar = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Bar", flags)foo.GetParameters()[0];
bool test = foo.ParameterType == bar.ParameterType; // false
```

I would like to write a method that compares two `T` based on their constraints, and returns *true* if they have same constraints.For example the above result should be true because both parameter doesn't have any constraint.

I can use [`GetGenericParameterConstraints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints(v=vs.110).aspx) method and compare the types but I want also perform a check for `class`, `struct` and `new()` constraints. Is there a way to do that using `Reflection` ?

Comment: Did you see the code example they have on the site? it shows comparations for `class`, `struct` and `new`

Comment: Have you seen this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [`GenericParameterAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.genericparameterattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your `foo.ParameterType` and `bar.ParameterType` instances: it returns an enumeration that contains all possible attributes for your type.

You'll be interested in:

- `ReferenceTypeConstraint` (if you added `class` as constraint)
- `NotNullableValueTypeConstraint` (if you added `struct` as constraint)
- `DefaultConstructorConstraint` (if not combined with `NotNullableValueTypeConstraint`, you added `new()` as constraint)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method if order of parameters are important:

```
private static bool CompareGenerics(MethodInfo m1, MethodInfo m2)
{
    var args1 = m1.GetGenericArguments();
    var args2 = m2.GetGenericArguments();

    if (args1.Length != args2.Length)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < args1.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((args1[i].GenericParameterAttributes ^ args2[i].GenericParameterAttributes) != 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```